# problem with implementation of MiniBatchKmeans result

Tags: python, k-means

Is it possible to have  different cluster size after several execution of my algorithm knowing that I use **MiniBatchKmeans**?
that is to say:

`cluster 1: size = 30 cluster 2: size = 24 cluster 3: size = 2`

after a new execution of the minibatch,
`cluster 1: size = 15 cluster 2: size = 20 cluster 3: size = 21`

```
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=nbK, init ='k-means++', max_iter=1000, max_no_improvement = 10)
kmeans.fit(X)

prediction = kmeans.predict(X)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should fix the random_state in order to have deterministic results.

```
kmeans = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=nbK, init ='k-means++', max_iter=1000, max_no_improvement = 10, random_state=10)
```

Check the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html